# invalid write of size 8 when using sem_t

Tags: c, valgrind

initially when I have only one sem_t *queue inside the struct, when I initialize it, the programs run without any errors and problems.

```
 #include <semaphore.h>

 typedef struct barrier {
   int count;
   sem_t *queue;
} barrier_t;

void barrier_init ( barrier_t *barrier, int count );

#include "barrier.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

// Initialise barrier here
void barrier_init ( barrier_t *barrier, int count ) 
{

  barrier->count = count;
  barrier->queue = malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
  sem_init(barrier->queue, 0, 0);

 }
```

however, when I have two sem_t in struct barrier when I initialize and run with Valgrind, it signals to me that there is an invalid write of size 8, even though the program runs and outputs normally.

```
#include "barrier.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
typedef struct barrier {
  int count;
  sem_t *queue, *mutex;
}  barrier_t;

void barrier_init ( barrier_t *barrier, int count ) 
{
 
  barrier->count = count;
  barrier->queue = malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
  barrier->mutex = malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
  sem_init(barrier->mutex, 0, 1);
  sem_init(barrier->queue, 0, 0);

}
void barrier_wait ( barrier_t *barrier ) 
{   
  sem_wait(barrier->mutex);
  barrier->count--;
  sem_post(barrier->mutex);

  if (barrier->count == 0) {      
    sem_post(barrier->queue);    
  }



  sem_wait(barrier->queue);
  sem_post(barrier->queue);
}

// Perform cleanup here if you need to
void barrier_destroy ( barrier_t *barrier ) 
{

  sem_destroy(barrier->queue);
  sem_destroy(barrier->mutex);
  free(barrier->queue);
  free(barrier->mutex);   
}
```

The main function was a template given which should not have any issues.
Valgrind has no issue with memory leaks as well only errors indicating invalid write and read of size 8. so here's the main function:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "barrier.h"

sem_t *common_sem;
int waiting_at_barrier = 0;

typedef struct thread_task {
  int       thread_id;
  barrier_t *barrier;
  int       thread_return;
  int       sleep_time;
} thread_task_t;


void* run_thread( void* task ) 
{
  thread_task_t* thread_task = (thread_task_t*) task;
  const int thread_id = thread_task->thread_id;
  barrier_t *barrier = thread_task->barrier;

  usleep( thread_task->sleep_time );

  sem_wait( common_sem );
  waiting_at_barrier++;
  sem_post( common_sem );

  printf ( "[Thread %2d] waiting on barrier\n", thread_id );
  barrier_wait( barrier );
  printf ( "[Thread %2d] exiting barrier\n", thread_id );
  thread_task->thread_return = waiting_at_barrier;

  pthread_exit(0);
  }

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{

  if (argc < 2) {
  printf("usage: %s threads [seed]\n", argv[0]);
  exit(1);
  }

  if (argc > 2) {
    srand(atoi(argv[2])); // [atoi] defaults to 0 if cannot be parsed.
  }

  const int total_threads = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 50;
  // initialise common semaphore
  common_sem = malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
  sem_init( common_sem, 0, 1 );


  barrier_t *barrier = malloc( sizeof(barrier_t) );
  barrier_init( barrier, total_threads );

  pthread_t threads[total_threads];
  thread_task_t *thread_tasks = malloc(sizeof(thread_task_t) * 
  total_threads);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < total_threads; i++) {
    thread_tasks[i].thread_id = i;
    thread_tasks[i].barrier = barrier;
    thread_tasks[i].sleep_time = (rand() % 500) * 1000;
    pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, run_thread, (void*) 
    &thread_tasks[i] );
  }

  // wait and collect the tasks
  bool error_found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < total_threads; i++) {
    pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );
    if (thread_tasks[i].thread_return < total_threads) {
    error_found = true;
    printf ( "[Thread %2d] exited with %d other tasks (expected: 
      %d)\n",i,thread_tasks[i].thread_return,
           total_threads );
    }
  }

  free(thread_tasks);

  barrier_destroy(barrier);
  free(barrier);

  sem_destroy( common_sem );
  free( common_sem );

  if (error_found) {
    printf ( "Incorrect executions found\n" );
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

THis is part of the Valgrind errors:

Invalid write of size 8 at 0x1098BB: barrier_init (in /home/hzxin/work/2106/lab3/L3/ex1/ex1) by 0x10948F:
main (in /home/hzxin/work/2106/lab3/L3/ex1/ex1)
Address 0x4a730b0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'dat 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

Comment: Please show `main`. Please add relevant `#include`s. Please create a full [MCVE]. The problem might be that `barrier` is invalid pointer.

Comment: @KamilCuk have updated the Main

Comment: what are your compilation and valgrind calls?

Comment: @Eben There is a Makefile given in the template the content of the Makefile is as follow: `CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDLIBS=-lpthread

.PHONY: clean

ex1: barrier.o ex1.o

barrier.o: barrier.c barrier.h

clean:
 rm barrier.o ex1.o ex1

.PHONY: all
all: ex1`

Comment: Yes, that Makefile just compiles it and links against pthread library

Comment: The code works for me without problems with `valgrind ./a.out 100`. What is in `barrier.h`? Did you recompile `ex1.o` after changing `barrier_t`?

Comment: @Eben Yea the programs run without failure. I am just confused why the programs lead to erros when i use two sem_t instead of one and the program somehow still run normally even tho Valgrind report invalid write.

Comment: @KamilCuk looking at the Makefile i think ex1.o is recompile, barrier.h contains only the declarations of the struct barrier and the relevent functions.

Comment: I added all of the above code in the same .c file, and it runs without issues and no reported errors in Valgrind.

Comment: Did you remember to update the struct barrier structure in both the header and c file when you changed it to have 2 semaphores? If there is a mismatch then you get an problem

Comment: `looking at the Makefile i think ex1.o is recompile` I see no `ex1.o: ex1.c barrier.h` in the comment you posted. I believe it will not - the error is consistent with that the `ex1.c` is using previous smaller struct definition.

Comment: @Eben yea just double checked everything is up to date.. if that's the case maybe it an issue with my ubuntu..

Comment: @KamilCuk i manually added ex1.c to be compile as well, but it still give me invalid write issue.. i am now thinking whether is it an issue with my ubuntu..

Comment: could you try the same as I did, just put all code in one single .c file and then compile and run it

Comment: @Eben oh my, when i put everything tgt it works without erros i am so lost now

Comment: @Eben I have figured out the problem now, i realize i have to make clean the files... sorry for the careless mistakes

Answer (score 1):

I added a small main function and also a simple deinit function.
Compiling with gcc 9.3.0 and checking with valgrind 3.15 yields no problem.
Double check how you are calling your functions.

Running your updated code in Valgrind works just fine for me.

Comment: Please don't include complete source code on answer as it makes evaluating the answer difficult. It's generally better to include only relevant lines and explain solution where necessary.

Comment: I have updated the main function, it was a template given which i do not know how to simplify.